# findText using regex for placeholders

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

I am trying to go through a documents and find all placeholders to replace them with text.

For example a document may contain something like {Name_dog}, {Name_cat}, etc...

I am using a regex in my find text as follow:

```
var regex = '\{Name_+\}';
var location =  part.findText(regex);
```

but it returns null. If I change the regex to '{Name_+' it returns rangeElement but it's not what I need. Tried to use combinations of * instead of + and } or \} instead of } but I still can not make it to work... I need to get any text that will follow {Name_whatever}

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex you are using, `\{Name_+\}`, means "{Name", followed by 1 or more "_", followed by "}", which is not what you want!

The `+` symbol in a regex means "1 or more of the preceding pattern".

Here is a visualisation of the regex you used: [http://regexper.com/#{Name_%2B}](http://regexper.com/#%5C%7BName_%2B%5C%7D)

What you actually want to say is probably something like: `\{Name_\w+\}`. Visualisation: [http://regexper.com/#{Name_\w%2B}](http://regexper.com/#%5C%7BName_%5Cw%2B%5C%7D)

`\w` means "any word character, i.e. a-z, A-Z, 0-9 or '_'". If this is too vague for your use case, e.g. you don't want the patern to match digits or underscores, you could use a regex like: `\{Name_[a-zA-Z]+\}`. Visualisation: [http://regexper.com/#{Name_[a-zA-Z]%2B}](http://regexper.com/#%5C%7BName_[a-zA-Z]%2B%5C%7D)